# Non-sequent figures with same number

Tags: floats, captions

I need to set the same figure number of two non-sequent figures (they are located in two different chapters). Is there any "captionsetup" option to achieve that? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\setcounter{figure}` to change the number that is used for the next caption. So: Before the `\caption` of the figure with the re-used number, set the figure counter to the old number minus one, and afterwards put it back to the value it had before.

Here, I provide an example where define two macros to make this more automated. With `\storefigurenumber`, you store the current figure number under some name specified as argument (like a `\label`; use after the `\caption`). Later, you can call `\mycaption` with the chosen name as first argument and the usual caption of the second argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\newcounter{storedfigurenumber}
\newcommand{\storefigurenumber}[1]{\newcounter{#1}\setcounter{#1}{\value{figure}}}
\newcommand{\mycaption}[2]{%
    \setcounter{storedfigurenumber}{\value{figure}}%
    \setcounter{figure}{\value{#1}}%
    \addtocounter{figure}{-1}%
    \caption{#2}%
    \setcounter{figure}{\value{storedfigurenumber}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{My first image}\storefigurenumber{first}
\end{figure}

\section{Second}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-b}
    \caption{My second image}
\end{figure}

\section{Third}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-c}
    \mycaption{first}{My third image}
\end{figure}

\section{Fourth}
\begin{figure}[!h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image-a}
    \caption{My fourth image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]